# Accented Characters not displaying in Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm having an issue with using accented (UTF8) characters as Javascript variables. The page is declared as UTF-8 in the META tag, as well as PHP header. The Javascript code (as displayed after page load) is as follows (truncated for brevity):

```
 Globals.shippingValues = $H({
                    address1: "25 Abbejet K�gerreveszak",
                    address2: "",
                    city: "Z�bev�r Abej�rn",
                    state: "KY",
                    zip: "51150"
    });
```

The values are actually variables passed via PHP:

```
    Globals.shippingValues = \$H({
        address1: "{$data['address1']}",
        address2: "{$data['address2']}",
        city: "{$data['city']}",
        state: "{$data['state']}",
        zip: "{$data['zip']}"
});
```

These $data characters display correctly on the site as HTML, but in the Javascript, they come through as unknown characters. This is stopping the entire addresses from being entered into the database, as the values become truncated after the first unknown.

Obviously, I could change the method in which the form is submitted and circumvent this issue, but I'd prefer to know how to fix this as is.

PHP: 5.3.20-pl0-gentoo
Server: NGNIX
Javascript: Prototype 1.7

Comment: You probably didn't save the file as UTF8

Comment: All my files are saved as UTF-8, PHP files, PHP template files and the Javascript. It's the default encoding in my text editor (Editpad)

Comment: If it helps, these characters (all non-ASCII) don't display in HTML comments, either, but display just fine in the actual HTML.